# Moderated mediation with dichotomous moderator and predictor and four continuous mediators

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I have a question regarding model specification for a moderated mediation model. I am working on a project in which I am trying to model the mediating effect of emotional experiences between the relationship of conditions on continuous outcomes.

[Model visualization here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ6Ul.jpg)

I was thinking of using lavaan, but I am struggling specifying the model correctly; specifically where and how to implement the moderator.

I suggest that different conditions affect emotional experiences differently, and that having access to social media (vs. not having access) affects this effect.

So I think I modeled the mediation model fairly correctly, but I don't know where and how to add the moderators.

```
zz <- "M1   M2   M3   M4   DV1   DV2   MO   IV
1      1.0  1.6  3.4  4.1  6.0   2.6   0.5  2.0  
2      2.5  2.2  2.8  2.5  3.1   5.0   0.5  2.0
3      3.0  3.4  6.4  1.0  6.8   3.1   0.5  2.0
4      4.8  3.6  4.4  2.1  4.4   4.3   -0.5 1.0
5      3.5  4.0  3.8  3.8  4.3   3.5   -0.5 1.0"

Data <- read.table(text = zz,
                   header = TRUE)
```

And my model specification would look like this (without the moderator)

```
model <- " # direct effect
         DV1 ~ c1*IV
         DV2 ~ c2*IV

       # mediators
         M1  ~ a1*IV
         DV1 ~ b11*M1
         DV2 ~ b12*M1

         M2  ~ a2*IV
         DV1 ~ b21*M2
         DV2 ~ b22*M2

         M3  ~ a3*IV
         DV1 ~ b31*M3
         DV2 ~ b32*M3

         M4  ~ a4*IV
         DV1 ~ b41*M4
         DV2 ~ b42*M4

       # indirect effect (a*b)
         indirect.disconnect := a1*b11 + a2*b21 + a3*b31 + a4*b41
         indirect.selfesteem := a1*b12 + a2*b22 + a3*b32 + a4*b42

       # total effect
         total.disconnect := c1 + a1*b11 + a2*b21 + a3*b31 + a4*b41
         total.selfesteem := c2 + a1*b12 + a2*b22 + a3*b32 + a4*b42"

fit <- sem(model,
       data = dat_sem)

summary(fit,
    standardized = TRUE,
    fit.measures = TRUE)
```

Hopefully this is the right place to post this question.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This looks more like a statistical modeling question. If so, you would do better to remove it here and post it on crossValidated. If you do this, consider adding additional details regarding sample size and the underlying concept driving your specific SEM construction. There is probably also an appropriate tag there as well.

Comment: Hi, I had it there before and was told its a software specific question and was put on hold. So I figured its more appropriate here. I rather need help using lavaan correctly.

Comment: Can you share some reproducible data? Can be the first line of your actual data or made up one.

Comment: Hi, I just added the first five rows of my data. I hope that helps?